# Changing the color of the web browser controls scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the web browser control in my windows application. I want to change the look and feel of the scrollbar. For which i found the link of code project given below.
which seems to be more cumbersome. So Instead of that is there any other way to customize scrollbars.I want to design scrollbar without up and down arrows. Just scroller. I am not able to do that with this code. Or else can I change the look and feel of the default scroll bar i.e. color width etc.

Comment: sorry the link is missing in question:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C

Comment: Can't you inject some CSS code into the loaded page? In fact, I believe the scroll bars are not owned by the control itself, but by the web page inside the control.

Comment: @Steve B -Actually I am working with windows form and in that form I have added web browser control. Can we use CSS in windows form? I have no idea. If yes please tell me how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: What you have to understand, is that the scroll bars are not managed byt the WebBrowserControl, but the web page itself. Actually, this is a scroll bar from Internet Explorer, not for the control itself. [Ria's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12725049/588868) illustrate what I mean. It shows how to customize the scrollbar of the page, not the control.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for explanation. Now I want to decrease the width of the scrollbar. Is there any property for that? If yes please tell me how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IHTMLDocument2.styleSheets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752607%28VS.85%29.aspx) to set styleSheets:

```
IHTMLDocument2 _htmlDocument = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
int length = _htmlDocument.styleSheets.length;
IHTMLStyleSheet styleSheet = _htmlDocument.createStyleSheet(@"", length + 1);
styleSheet.addRule("BODY", "scrollbar-face-color: #FF0000;");
styleSheet.addRule("BODY", "scrollbar-highlight-color: #FF00FF;");
styleSheet.addRule...
```

or you can set `CSS` directly in `HTML` code:

***`CSS:`***

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
<!--
BODY
{
scrollbar-face-color: #FF0000;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #00FF00;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #00FFFF;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #0000FF;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-track-color: #FFFF00;
}
-->
</STYLE>
```

and in your ***`C#`*** code set [`WebBrowser.DocumentText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><head><STYLE type=\"text/css\"><!--BODY{scrollbar-face-color: #FF0000;scrollbar-highlight-color: #FF00FF;scrollbar-3dlight-color: #00FF00;scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #00FFFF;scrollbar-shadow-color: #0000FF;scrollbar-arrow-color: #FF00FF;scrollbar-track-color: #FFFF00;}--></STYLE></head><body>aaaa</body></html>";
```

note that: You can only see the coloured scrollbar if you run IE 5.5.